# Float figure - why does left go right and right go anywhere?

Tags: css, html

Float left should be pretty simple: float the figure to the left. But instead of floating left, HTML5 randomly decides to maybe float left, maybe float right(ish), maybe neither.  What is it with figures floating any which way they want?

My expected output is something like this:

[image: like this]

My actual output is something like this:

[image: like this]

*(Yes, those examples do not have the same number of images. That is a mistake in creating the examples. It took me too long making them to go back and start again. The examples were meant to have the same number of images.)*

Here is the CSS code in the header:

```
    <style>
        figure.cover { float:left; margin: 0; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 0; width: 50%;}
        figure.cover img {float:left; width:100%;}
        figure.cover figcaption {text-align: center; font-style: italic;}       
        figure.left { float:left; margin: 0; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 0; width: 45%;}
        figure.left img {float:left; width:100%;}
        figure.left figcaption {text-align: center; font-style: italic;}
        figure.right { float:right; margin: 0; padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 10px;  padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 10px; width: 45%;}
        figure.right img {float:right; width:100%;}
        figure.right figcaption {text-align: center; font-style: italic;}           
        figure.center { display:block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 75%;}
        figure.center img { display:block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 100%;}
        figure.center figcaption {text-align: center; font-style: italic;}
    </style>
```

And here is the HTML I'm using to render the images (repeated several times, obviously).

```
<figure class="left">
    <img src="image 2">
    <figcaption>
        Lorem Ipsum
    </figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="right">
    <img src="image 3">
    <figcaption>
        Lorem Ipsum
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Attempted solutions:

- Resizing images and substituting different files, to rule out specific images causing the problem somehow,
- adjusting padding above and below figures,
- inserting breaks after the right floated figure,
- nesting the paired figures into a figure.master element,
- adding display:block in the CSS for the img descriptions for the figure.right and figure.left classes,
- inserting overflow:hidden for the same,

and a few other tinkerings I can't even remember at this point.

Wrapping the right and left pairs in divs is NOT an option, as it would require a ground up rebuild of the entire site.

Comment: Based on the CSS you have so far and the example HTML you have added (which I repeated a few times in a stack snippet), everything seems fine. So either your actual markup is not as simple as your sample HTML in your question, or there's additional CSS on your site not related to this chart that's interfering, or you've got a typo somewhere.

Comment: Pretty sure your images do not actually have the exact same heights, as your expected result suggests. _"Float left should be pretty simple:"_ - that's your misconception right there ...  _"float the figure to the left."_ - yeah, no, not really ... what it really says is, float following inline content _around_ this element (that you applied float to.) With images (or generally, elements) of different heights, you might get a more pleasant result using `display:inline-block` instead of float. Plus `vertical-align:top`, and you will at least not have elements that get stuck in the middle.

Comment: But of course there will still be different spacing between elements of different heights; the tallest one in a row decides where the net row starts. If you want more than that, you want to look into either flexbox, grid layout, or a solution like masonry.js

Comment: Cbroe, I've done several substitutions for the actual image files.  In one test, I used the same image for each figure.  The problem remained the exact same.  Not only does the pairing become disordered, it becomes disordered in the exact same pattern.  The images are all very nearly the same height.  They all started very large, around 6000x4000, and I've resized them to roughly 600x400.  The exact dimension differences are fairly negligible.

Inline-block bunches the images to the left of the screen, or has no effect at all.

Comment: Apple, can you edit your question with the full HTML you've got working and any additional relevant CSS that's not already included? You can use a service like https://placeholder.com to insert images that are the exact same size as the ones you're using on your site, to truly reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I think I've come up with a fairly simple (too simple, should have thought of it sooner?) solution.  Inserted a `<div style="clear: both;"></div>` after each pairing.